# Filter Rows in DataGridView that does not match a String

Tags: c#, .net, string, datagridview, filter

I'm using the following code to filter items in a DataGridView based on text match using the following code

```
 //bs is a BindingSource
 bs.Filter = string.Format("Result LIKE '%{0}%'", "match");
```

I need to filter those items that does not match a string .. how can i do this?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand correctly, but `"NOT(Result LIKE '%{0}%')"` is not working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know you can just use `NOT LIKE` in this way:

```
bs.Filter = string.Format("Result NOT LIKE '%{0}%'", "match");
```